# Minimum system requirements to run Mist

Tags: mist

I am running Mist on VPS with 512MB RAM, but it crashes, and the process is killed automatically. What are the minimum system requirements to run Mist and how much memory do I need?

Answer (score 1):

On my Linux Vms I have 2GB allocated and up to 1GB in use.

It looks like 1 GB is a minimal requirement, but blockchain synchronization may take a while.

On Windows Vms - the same plus 500 MB.

Comment: I upgraded my VPS to 2GB, now it's working fine. I know on more than 1 GB works good, but what exact minimum configuration is required was my concern.

Comment: I am not sure that there is exact minimum configuration for blockchain client as system requirements depend on blockchain stuff (nodes, blocks etc)